# How do I reduce a Product Excerpt word count? The usual approach is just not working for me

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently creating a WordPress Theme, with WooCommerce functionalty.  On the Homepage, I have created a 'Most Recent Products' section, whereby I have inserted `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` within the index.php file.

I wish to limit the excerpt, by 20 words.  To achieve this, I entered the following code into the functions.php file as suggested by the WordPress Codex:

```
function theme_name_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'theme_name_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.  Is anyone able to see if I am overlooking something simple or maybe the code is outdated etc?  I have tried various combinations, and followed several online resources but just cannot seem to modify the excerpt.

Comment: Is the home page created by just placing a template like home.php or front-page.php, using the hierarchy described here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and letting WordPress decide when to use it? I've seen themes that `include` page content using a hook, which in some cases can cause other hooks to be skipped or run in the wrong order, but I'm not sure if that is the case here.

Comment: In terms of home();, this would be the Blog page. In terms of the actual homepage, this is the index.php file.  I'm not sure if this is a factor but the concerned file is being called in the index.php file through `<?php get_template_part( 'templates/latest-products' ); ?>` As a test, I did remove this entry and placed the template's content directly into the index.php file but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured out what was causing the issue.

If you are using WooCommerce, and manually enter information into the 'Product Short Description' field, this will override any excerpt length you may set.